# How to wrap lines within columns in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a comma delimited file which I am formatting to create 2 columns using printf. I am using awk to group the contents into similar groups so I can print them into nicely formatted columns.

The formatting works but the contents of the array wrap onto new lines instead of wrapping within the column itself.

Input file example:

```
1,test,test1,test1
2,test,test1,test2
2,test,test1,test2
2,test,test1,test2
2,test,test1,test2
2,test,test1,test2
2,test,test1,test2
2,test,test1,test2
2,test,test1,test2
2,test,test1,test2
2,test,test1,test2
2,test,test1,test2
2,test,test1,test2`
```

Command used:

```
awk -F"," 'NR>1 {a[$3]=a[$3] ? a[$3]", "$4" ("$2")" : $4" ("$2")"}
  END {for (i in a) {print i":"a[i]}}' test.dat |
sort |
awk -F":" 'BEGIN { printf "%-15s %-10s\n", "COLUMN1","COLUMN2"; printf "%-15s %-10s\n", "-----------","----------"}
  { printf "%-15s %-10s\n", $1,$2}'
```

I am also aware about and have tried using `column -t -s","` and `pr`

The outcome is like (simulating example):

```
COLUMN1     COLUMN2
========     =======
1            test1
2            test2, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2,test2, test2, test2,test2, test2, test2, test2, test2
```

How can I wrap the second column (even the first one if it is too long) so that it fits within its frame?

```
COLUMN1     COLUMN2
========     =======
1            test1
2            test2, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2,test2, test2, 
             test2,test2, test2, test2, test2, test2
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images) and your desired output for **that** sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do wrt grouping fields and running the command you posted against the input you posted doesn't produce anything like the output you say it does so that doesn't help. Please clarify your requirements and make sure that the output you post is the output you get and expect from the input you post.

Comment: maybe `column -t -s"," -c 50`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's pretend this is what your original script is doing given your posted sample input and the output you say you get:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="\t" }
{ vals[$1] = ($1 in vals ? vals[$1] ", " : "") $4 }
END {
    print "column1", "column2"
    print "=======", "======="

    for (key in vals) {
        print key, vals[key]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
column1 column2
======= =======
1       test1
2       test2, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2
```

Would that be a good starting point for your question and now you want to wrap each column? If so then I'd take advantage of an existing UNIX tool like `fold` or `fmt` to do the wrapping for you so you don't have to write your own code to handle splitting on spaces vs mid-word, etc.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="\t" }
{ vals[$1] = ($1 in vals ? vals[$1] ", " : "") $4 }
END {
    print "column1", "column2"
    print "=======", "======="

    for (key in vals) {
        numKeyLines = wrap(key,15,keyArr)
        numValLines = wrap(vals[key],50,valArr)
        numLines = (numKeyLines > numValLines ? numKeyLines : numValLines)
        for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++) {
            print keyArr[lineNr], valArr[lineNr]
        }
    }
}

function wrap(inStr,wid,outArr,         cmd,line,numLines) {
    if ( length(inStr) > wid ) {
        cmd = "printf \047%s\n\047 \"" inStr "\" | fold -s -w " wid+0
        while ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
            outArr[++numLines] = line
        }
        close(cmd)
    }
    else {
        outArr[++numLines] = inStr
    }
    return numLines+0
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
column1 column2
======= =======
1       test1
2       test2, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2,
        test2, test2, test2, test2, test2
```

If you have a lot of fields that need to be wrapped then it won't be fast due to spawning a subshell for each call to `fold` so here's an all awk version that splits at spaces when possible, test it for edge cases and massage to suit:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="\t" }
{ vals[$1] = ($1 in vals ? vals[$1] ", " : "") $4 }
END {
    print "column1", "column2"
    print "=======", "======="

    for (key in vals) {
        numKeyLines = wrap(key,15,keyArr)
        numValLines = wrap(vals[key],50,valArr)
        numLines = (numKeyLines > numValLines ? numKeyLines : numValLines)
        for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++) {
            print keyArr[lineNr], valArr[lineNr]
        }
    }
}

function wrap(inStr,wid,outArr,         lineEnd,numLines) {
    while ( length(inStr) > wid ) {
        lineEnd = ( match(substr(inStr,1,wid),/.*[[:space:]]/) ? RLENGTH - 1 : wid )
        outArr[++numLines] = substr(inStr,1,lineEnd)
        inStr = substr(inStr,lineEnd+1)
        sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",inStr)
    }
    outArr[++numLines] = inStr
    return numLines
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
column1 column2
======= =======
1       test1
2       test2, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2,
        test2, test2, test2, test2, test2
```

Comment: Ed, I would happily buy a book of your SO answers.

Comment: @ghoti Mail me the $1mil and I'll start writing it for you :-).

Comment: how do you do this for a file with M columns, and only for the Nth column or only if text is longer than P characters?

Comment: @CostinGușă ask a new question, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that uses perl instead of awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($col1, $col4, @col4data);

print <<EOF;
COLUMN1     COLUMN2
=======     =======
EOF

{
  my $line = <>;
  chomp $line;
  ($col1, $col4data[0]) = (split /,/, $line)[0,3];
}

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($c, $a) = (split /,/)[0,3];
  if ($c ne $col1) {
    $col4 = join ", ", @col4data;
    write;
    @col4data = ();
    $col1 = $c;
  }
  push @col4data, $a;
}

$col4 = join ", ", @col4data;
write;

format STDOUT =
@<<<<<<<    ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$col1,      $col4
~~          ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            $col4
.
```

Example:

```
$ perl columns.pl input.csv
COLUMN1     COLUMN2
=======     =======
1           test1
2           test2, test2, test2,
            test2, test2, test2,
            test2, test2, test2,
            test2, test2, test2
```

The magic here is doing the line wrapping using an [output format](https://perldoc.pl/perlform)'s fill mode. Adjust the width as needed by adding more `<`'s to the obvious parts in the `format` description.